# Order list or trades history Btce via api

Tags: api, btce, trade

Im trying to get my orders list or trades list via Btc-e Api but it always return 0 is bugged or what ?

```
 if (accountKey != null && accountSecret != null)
            {
                btcApi = new BtceApi(accountKey, accountSecret);
                info = btcApi.GetInfo();
                int ceva=info.TransactionCount;
                var transHistory = btcApi.GetTransHistory();
                var tradeHistory = btcApi.GetTradeHistory(count: 20);
                var orderList = btcApi.GetOrderList(count: 20);
                var tList = BtceApiV3.GetTrades(new BtcePair[]{BtcePair.ltc_usd},20);


            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post, but I stumbled on it while asking myself the same question. The answer is to use the ActiveOrders method (which I don't think is implemented in the  c# BtceAPI)

Comment: actually i modified the api and its ok now